# Why C# doesn't simply translate in the best available option?

Tags: c#, performance, compilation

I was wondering how it is possible for 2 exactly equivalent peace of code to have differences in performance.

I don't know if it's still the case but I know that a `for` loop used to be faster than the `foreach` equivalent.

The same goes for Linq.
I don't quite understand why would this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    ListDec = new List<decimal>();
    foreach (string s in myStrings)
        ListDec.Add(decimal.Parse(s));
}
```

be consinstntly 6% to 8% faster then

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    ListDec = myStrings.Select(decimal.Parse).ToList();
```

Probably I don't understand how compilers work, but intuitively I tend to ask myself if you design a language, and it turns out that one element is consistently slower that one of its equivalents, why don't you just make the compiler of your language translate the slower one in the faster one?

A compiler could simply convert a `foreach` loop in the equivalent `for` loop, and a linq expression in it's vanilla equivalent. This would make having differences in performance almost impossible because the fastest option would always be picked, in the end, at execution. While the coder could just pick the one he prefers without having to care about performance.
Sounds like an ideal world, but since our friends at Microsoft are not exactly that kind of dump guys, there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: The compiler isn't ever going to be able to optimise out a call to a method (in this case, `.Select()`). The compiler has no idea what the side-effects of that call are.

Comment: Calling @EricLippert to the stand :-)

Comment: Eric Lippert has already discussed this nicely in detail in many of his articles. There is even a good chance that this question is a duplicate.